# Controller Method is not getting triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have recently started exploring Spring boot. I am following https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jdbctemplate-postgresql-example/ documentation.

I have created all files as instructed in the documentation.

Here goes my code:

******AppApplication.java

```
`package com.triveni.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication

public class AppApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
   }

}`
```

***** IProductRepository *****

```
`package com.triveni.repository;

import com.triveni.models.ProductModel;

import java.util.List;

public interface IProductRepository {
    int create(ProductModel productModel);
    int update (ProductModel productModel);
    ProductModel findById(int id);
    List<ProductModel> findAll();

    List<ProductModel> findByActive(boolean active);
}`
```

***** ProductModel.java *****

```
package com.triveni.models;

public class ProductModel {
    private int productId;
    private String productName;
    private int cost;
    private Boolean active;
    private int descriptionId;



    public ProductModel(int productId, String productName, int cost, Boolean active, int descriptionId){
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.active = active;
        this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId){
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public long getProductId(){
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName){
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return productName;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setDescriptionId(int descriptionId) {
        this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
    }

    public int getDescriptionId() {
        return descriptionId;
    }


}
```

*** Product Repository *****

```
package com.triveni.data;

import com.triveni.models.ProductModel;
import com.triveni.repository.IProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class ProductRepository implements IProductRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public int create(ProductModel productModel) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO public.product(\n" +
                "\t\"productId\", \"productName\", cost, \"DescriptionId\", active)\n" +
                "\tVALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",new Object[]{productModel.getProductId(),productModel.getProductName(),
                productModel.getCost(), productModel.getDescriptionId(),productModel.getActive()});
    }

    @Override
    public int update(ProductModel productModel) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductModel findById(int id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductModel> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT \"productId\", \"productName\", cost, \"DescriptionId\", active\n" +
                "\tFROM public.product",BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(ProductModel.class));
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductModel> findByActive(boolean active) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

***** ProductController.java *****

```
package com.triveni.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.triveni.data.ProductRepository;
import com.triveni.models.ProductModel;
import com.triveni.repository.IProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

   @GetMapping("/product")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts(){
       try{
        List<ProductModel> products = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
           productRepository.findAll().forEach(products::add);;
           return new ResponseEntity<>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
       }catch (Exception e){
           return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

       }
   }

}
```

[My Project Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyPnz.png)

I am getting following error

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 27 13:51:39 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

*****Output****

```
/Users/chhayatiwari/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=51857:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/chhayatiwari/Desktop/Work/TriveniApp-Service/app/target/classes:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.1/spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.0.1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.5/logback-classic-1.4.5.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.5/logback-core-1.4.5.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.19.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.19.0/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.6/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.1/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.1/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.1/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.14.1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.14.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.14.1/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.4.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.3/spring-web-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.10.2/micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.2/micrometer-commons-1.10.2.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.3/spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.3/spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.3/spring-context-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.3/spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.3/spring-core-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.3/spring-jcl-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jdbc/3.0.0/spring-data-jdbc-3.0.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-relational/3.0.0/spring-data-relational-3.0.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.0.0/spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.5.1/postgresql-42.5.1.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.5.0/checker-qual-3.5.0.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.22/spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.3/spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:/Users/chhayatiwari/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.3/spring-tx-6.0.3.jar com.triveni.app.AppApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

2022-12-27T20:17:11.351+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.triveni.app.AppApplication           : Starting AppApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 3695 (/Users/chhayatiwari/Desktop/Work/TriveniApp-Service/app/target/classes started by chhayatiwari in /Users/chhayatiwari/Desktop/Work/TriveniApp-Service/app)
2022-12-27T20:17:11.353+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.triveni.app.AppApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-27T20:17:11.664+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-27T20:17:11.671+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2022-12-27T20:17:11.919+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-27T20:17:11.924+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-27T20:17:11.925+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2022-12-27T20:17:11.972+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-27T20:17:11.973+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 589 ms
2022-12-27T20:17:12.162+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-27T20:17:12.282+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6680f714
2022-12-27T20:17:12.283+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-27T20:17:12.343+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-27T20:17:12.348+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [           main] com.triveni.app.AppApplication           : Started AppApplication in 1.206 seconds (process running for 1.435)
2022-12-27T20:19:18.599+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-27T20:19:18.599+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-27T20:19:18.604+05:30  INFO 3695 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
```

Comment: You're trying to go to an address that probably doesn't exist. What address are you going to?

Comment: @fatih I am going to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products

Comment: @ChhayaTiwari it should be `localhost:8080/api/v1/product` not `products`. check your own API to see if you type the URL correctly

Comment: @TanSang still the same error

Comment: The error said that you are calling for a URL that doesn't exist and since you don't have a default 404 error page, the application return that error. So, just try to call a valid URL that is available.

Comment: Looks like something else I am missing

Comment: Can you please share/add to original post any output that you see in your IDE?

Comment: Is it adding another line when you try to reach that controller? Have you tried it through Postman? If so, which response code did you get? Can you add a breakpoint to the line that you have in catch condition and see if hits that line?

Comment: @patrinox 

tried through post man

{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-27T15:13:25.861+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/testMyController"
}


Really not sure why 404

Comment: Finally created a new App again. This time added dependencies directly using spring.io and tried to run its working. I am able to hit the controller.

But still not sure why previous one is not working. I also tried to replace the pom.xml content with new one.

Comment: It seems that you were trying to reach to an API that doesn't exist. Your controller path should be "/api/v1/product" but postman shows that you were trying to reach "/api/testMyController"

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to annotation **@CrossOrigin("*")** after **@RestController**.

Comment: Tried. it didnt work

Comment: mmm remove this : **@RequestMapping("/api/v1")** and then try to call your web service with this link **localhost:8080/product**. don't forget to keep the crossOrigin annotation. It is the same thing but let's try.

Comment: Tried this as well. Issue persists

Comment: okey, you can debug your project, put some break points in your method **getAllProducts** and see if you can access to it or not. If you access into the method then the problem it is not relited to the url. If not the problem is in the Url.

Comment: I am not able to access the method. Breakpoint is not hitting at all

Comment: But it does hit AppApplication method in AppApplication.java file

Comment: Strange!! Every thing sames to be okey.

Comment: I am using Intellij for debugging. Is that is causing problem. Let me try with eclipse once

Comment: Doesn't work in eclipse too

Comment: **http://localhost:8080/** is that url work fine for you??

Comment: there also same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are just launching the spring application and on launch, this error shows up. In order to test your URL you can type
`<YOUR-URL>/app/v1/product`
This should return you the Response you are looking for.

Comment: Tried. Not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove ResponseEntity<List> from method and instead return a simple String and check if the method invoked or not. If it works properly then go to the next step and invoke the repository.

Comment: Tried this as well. I think it can be some other issue. I have removed every thing just returning simple string.

@GetMapping("/test")
 public String testMyController() {
  return "hello";
 }

Still not working